# pyautogui как передвинуть мышку в указанную переменную?

Tags: python, pyautogui

нужно прочитать файл и передвинуть мышь на по координатам из файла. они записаны в виде posX:posY

```
import pyautogui as pg
import time as tm

with open("pos.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        posX, posY = line.strip().split(":")
tm.sleep(1)
pg.moveTo()
```